# Convert input code in row by column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list

I have an input file which format looks like as below,(input.txt)

Suppose this format is random hexadecimal data as follows:

```
20 3h 4f 57 56 37
4a 2d 33 45 10 2a
23 47 4c
```

And I want to convert this file into another format as follows: (output.txt)

```
hform_param00 = 20
hform_param01 = 3h
hform_param02 = 4f
.
.
hform_param05 = 37
hform_param06 = 4a 
.
.
hform_param12 = 23
hform_param13 = 47 
hform_param14 = 4c
```

How can I deal with it?
I've thought about pandas dataframe,
but the overall structure of input is quite different than I expected.

Any solution or hint would be much appreciated Thanks!

Comment: The input is an actual binary file that - when looked at with a hex editor - looks like the above. Or are we speaking of a text file that is formatted in the manner presented. Makes quite the difference when reading. Dataframes seem to be a very counter intuitive choice, since you have serial data. The procedure you need could look like this: 1) read two numbers from input 2) write to output, following the format you have specified, keep a counter variable for the prefix of each line.

Comment: @FlyingTeller the latter one is correct I am saying of a text file that is formatted in the shown manner.. can you show me any sample for this?? Cus I am quite not used to use dataframe..

Comment: Why do you want to use a Dataframe? Is this a hard requirement (assignment or similar), because I really cannot see how that would be a reasonable datastructure in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reading in the txt file, replace any new lines (\n) with a space. Then use the string split method on any spaces to turn the string into a list of values.

```
f = open("input.txt", "r")
input_txt = f.read()
input_txt = input_txt.replace('\n', ' ').split(' ')
```

If you would then like to store it in an output text file you can iterate over each list entry. Write each entry with its associated index on a new line in the output.txt file

```
f = open("output.txt", "w")
for idx, val in enumerate(input_txt):        
    f.write(f"hform_param{str(idx).zfill(2)} = {val}\n")
f.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You can directly use `input_txt = f.read().split()`, or more memory efficient for large files a double for loop on the lines and chunks.

Answer (score 0):

here is another example with ***with*** statement ...

```
string = ""

index = 0

with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        clean = line.replace('\n', '')
        field = clean.split(" ")
        for item in field:
            if index < 10:
                string +=  "hform_param0" + str(index) + " = " + item + "\n"
                index += 1
                continue 
            string +=  "hform_param" + str(index) + " = " + item + "\n"
            index += 1

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(string)
```

[image]